# how to get javascript variable value in different variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `2-9` value stored in a single variable in JavaScript.

But I want `2` to be stored in `a` variable and `9` stored in `b` variable.

For example :

```
<script>
var a = "2-9";
</script>
```

And I want to,

```
<script>
var a = "2";
var b = "9";
</script>
```

Please help me.

Comment: what do you mean by `minimum name` and `maximum name`..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use .split() in javascript

```
var a = "2-9";

var c = a.split("-");

a = c[0]; // it returns 2

var b = c[1];  // it returns 9
```

Comment: What about multi-digit numbers?

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `charAt()` method of `String` in javascript.

```
var a = string.charAt(0);
var b = string.charAt(2);
```

where `string` is "2-9".

**I suppose** that your string, wouldn't have the form "2-10", because in this case that will not work.

If that's the case then you have to use the `split()` method of `String` in javascript.

```
var c = string.split('-');
var a = c[0];
var b = c[1];
```

For futher documentation about these methods in javascript plese refer to the following links:

[JavaScript String charAt() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_charat.asp)

[JavaScript String split() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

Comment: it not works for double digit value

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)**:

> The split() method splits a String object into an array of strings by
>   separating the string into substrings.

```
var a = "2-9",
    b = a.split('-')[1];
a = a.split('-')[0];
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xy6A8/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is this:

```
<script>
    var string_value = "2-9".split('-'),
        minimum_name = string_value[0], // 2
        maximum_name = string_value[1]; // 9
</script>
```

---

Make use of `.split()` which creates an array out of a string, so you can split it by `-` then  you can assign the values with their indexes like `[0], [1]`.